# ArcGIS REST web_map_as_json definitionExpression

Tags: javascript, json, rest, arcgis

I'm using Javascript to make a REST call to the `ExportWebMap` function on an `ArcGIS 10.5` server, which returns a map image. An image of the map is returned but it shows ALL the points when I only want one. I think my **defitinitionExpression** is being ignored. I've looked through docs and forums but I don't see my mistake.

MAP QUERY URL: I can successfully query the `MapServer` to get a single point by `OBJECTID`

```
https://&lt;baseUrl>/&lt;arcserver>/rest/services/&lt;project>/&lt;map>/MapServer/export
```

REST URL:

```
https://&lt;baseUrl>/&lt;arcserver>/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute
```

Here are my parameters when I post to Export Web Map

```
Layout_Template: MAP_ONLY,
Format: PNG32,
f: json
Web_Map_as_JSON:
{
    "mapOptions":
    {
        "showAttribution":false,
        "extent":
        {
            "xmin":-118.85360990096176,
            "ymin":33.99062491328014,
            "xmax":-118.75318799544432,
            "ymax":34.04042561067984,
            "spatialReference":
            {
                "wkid":4326
            }
        },
        "spatialReference":
        {
            "wkid":4326
        }
    },
    "operationalLayers":
    [
        {
            "id":null,
            "title":"All Wells",
            "opacity":1,
            "url":"https://<baseUrl>/<arcserver>/rest/services/<project>/<map>/MapServer",
            "layers":
            {
                "id":0,
                "layerDefinition":
                {
                    "definitionExpression":"OBJECTID=27100"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "baseMap":
    {
        "title":"Street Basemap",
        "baseMapLayers":
        [
            {
                "url":"https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer",
                "opacity":1
            }
        ]
    },
    "exportOptions":
    {
        "dpi":96,
        "outputSize":[250,210]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by changing the operational layer from a map server to a feature server and moving the layerDefinition. My understanding is the map server is able to do what I wanted but there might be a server configuration option I am not aware of.

```
Web_Map_as_JSON:
{
    "mapOptions":
    {
        "showAttribution":false,
        "extent":
        {
            "xmin":-118.85360990096176,
            "ymin":33.99062491328014,
            "xmax":-118.75318799544432,
            "ymax":34.04042561067984,
            "spatialReference":
            {
                "wkid":4326
            }
        },
        "spatialReference":
        {
            "wkid":4326
        }
    },
    "operationalLayers":
    [
        {
            opacity: 1,
            url: "https://<baseUrl>/<arcserver>/rest/services/<project>/<map>/FeatureServer/0",
            layerDefinition: {
                definitionExpression: "OBJECTID=27100"
            }
        },
    ],
    "baseMap":
    {
        "title":"Street Basemap",
        "baseMapLayers":
        [
            {
                "url":"https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer",
                "opacity":1
            }
        ]
    },
    "exportOptions":
    {
        "dpi":96,
        "outputSize":[250,210]
    }
}
```